# Select value of cell to the left of max value in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to select the value of the cell to the left of max value of a column in Google sheets. Please see attached sample code and expected result:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgzOxj5uiUnan7ODS1o50GSStLAwczYO6dDFdjccWvg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Google Sheet, I propose such solution: `=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(MAX(A2:B5),B1:B5,0))`:
`INDEX()` returns the content of a cell specified by row and column offset. So as arguments you need to put:

1. Reference range
2. `MATCH()` will give you the relative position of the value, in this case, the `MAX()` value. Put 0 as the final argument as you need to find the exact value and your range is unsorted